# How to change user role in Orchard with C#

Tags: orchardcms

I've written a POST method for the front-end of my website. 
I want to change my user's role to my custom role that I've called "Disqualified" when I POST to my method.

How to do it?

Comment: You should post some of the things you have tried and explain what does not work as expected in order to ge a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do first is define the role with the name ie. "Disqualified". Take a look into `Orchard.Roles` module to see how to do it programmatically.

Then your class with the logic you're looking for, should look like this:

```cs
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly IRepository<UserRolesPartRecord>     _userRolesRepository;
    private readonly IRoleService _roleService;
    private readonly INotifier _notifier;
    private readonly IRoleEventHandler _roleEventHandlers;

    public YourClass(
        IRepository<UserRolesPartRecord> userRolesRepository, 
        IRoleService roleService, 
        INotifier notifier,
        IRoleEventHandler roleEventHandlers) {

        _userRolesRepository = userRolesRepository;
        _roleService = roleService;
        _notifier = notifier;
        _roleEventHandlers = roleEventHandlers;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public void DisqualifyUser(int userId)
    {
        var disqualifiedRole = _roleService.GetRoleByName("Disqualified");
        _userRolesRepository.Create(new UserRolesPartRecord { UserId = userId, Role = disqualifiedRole });
        _roleEventHandlers.UserAdded(new UserAddedContext {Role = addingRole, User = model.User});

        _notifier.Warning(T("User has been Disqualified"));
    }
}
```

I hope the code is pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to create a role. The best place is a migration class:

```
public class MyRoles {
    public const string Disqualified = "Disqualified";
}

public class MyMigrations : DataMigrationImpl {
    private readonly IRoleService _roleService;
    
    public Migrations(IRoleService roleService) {
        _roleService = roleService;
    }

    public int Create() {
        _roleService.CreateRole(MyRoles.Disqualified);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then, you need to write an action which processes a request:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private IRepository<UserRolesPartRecord> _repository;
    private IMembershipService _membershipService;

    public MyController(IMembershipService membershipService, IRepository<UserRolesPartRecord> repository) {
        _repository = repository;
        _membershipService = membershipService;
    }

    public ActionResult Disqualify(string userName) {
        var user = _membershipService.GetUser(userName);
        if (user == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid username");

        var role = _roleService.GetRoleByName(MyRoles.Disqualified);
        _repository.Create(new UserRolesPartRecord {UserId = user.Id, Role = role});

        // this can be replaced with INotifier as well
        return RedirectToAction("UserDisqualified");            
    }
}
```